# Центровка в таблице android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

столкнулся с проблемой центровки поля "textView" в таблице "TableLaout".

Мне нужно выровнять 3-тью запись относительно правого края, но тег "android:layout_alignParentRigt="true"" не работают в таблице и запись остается на своем месте.

[image]

Может кто знает как поступить в этой ситуации?

P.s. "TextView" можно заменить на кнопку.

UDP ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:backgroundTintMode="src_atop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_name" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinerKek"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablKek"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="1)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="10:30 - 10:40"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="TextView" />

            </TableRow>


        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: обновил ответ, попробуйте пожалуйста, только кнопку я вашу убрал и тип макета немного изменил под свой проект, вам самое главное взять оттуда таблицу и все

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Решить данную проблему можно так:

1. поставить у таблицы - `fill_parent`
2. И дальше установить у того `textView` который хотите выровнять - `android:layout_gravity="right"`

либо добавить `layout_weight` и установить ширину какая вам нужна.

### UPDATE

Посмотрел вашу разметку и сделал у себя тоже самое, вот рабочий вариант:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablKek"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="20">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="1)"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="2"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="10:30 - 10:40"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_weight="17"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

вот скриншот из редактора:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

должно работать нормально. Если что-то не получится - пишите, постараемся помочь :)

Comment: Не совсем понял что вы имеете ввиду, можете по подробнее? 
И к слову я мог бы установить отступ от строки но тогда на разных телефонах та строка будет на разном расстоянии от правого края.

Comment: с учетом того что есть только картинка я на этом и строю свой ответ)) у вас есть tablelayout, в моем ответе это называется таблица, а дальше все по пунктам :)

Comment: Я самую малость новичок в Android Studio, Java и тд, я не знаю как поставить этот параметр, могу предположить что в XML файл через "android:", но он помечает эту строку как неверную.

Comment: в xml там где таблица есть тег android:layout_width, вот там в двойных скобках поставьте `fill_parent`, дальше найдите textView который вам нужен и поставьте там строку которая выделена в 2 пункте моего ответа,  и должно все получится)

Comment: Теперь текст смещается, но только вверх и вниз.

Comment: Без разметки сложновато, может добавите если не сложно?) Кнопка Править возле вопроса ;)

Comment: Добавил, и поскольку нужно 15 символов я напишу кря. Кря.

Comment: `fill_parent` уже лет шесть как deprecated, не стоит его использовать.